# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x92 in position 359: invalid start byte

Tags: python, utf-8, decode, codec

First time poster, bear with me...

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys, os
count = 0
filename = "data2.txt"
file = open(filename, "r")


s1 = input("What do you want to search for? ")
search = s1.lower()

words = search.split()

def restart_program():
    """Restarts the current program.
    Note: this function does not return. Any cleanup action (like
    saving data) must be done before calling this function."""
    python = sys.executable
    os.execl(python, python, * sys.argv)

def countlines():  #count length of file
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        count = 0
        for line in f:
            count += 1
        return count
total = countlines()
totp1 = total + 1

with open(filename) as f:
  currpos = 0
  for line in f:
    currpos += 1
    line2 = line.lower()
    if currpos < totp1:
      if len(search.split()) == 2:
        if line2.find(words[0]) != -1 and line2.find(words[1]) != -1:
          print(line)
      if len(search.split()) == 1:
        if line2.find(search) != -1:
          print(line)
          #restart_program()
      if search == "quit":
        print('Exiting')
        break
      if search == "exit":
        print('Exiting')
        break
    if currpos == total:
      restart_program()
```

When I run this code on Repl.it it runs without issue and does just what its supposed to do.  However when I run it on my laptop (Arch) I get this error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./search", line 23, in <module>
    total = countlines()
  File "./search", line 20, in countlines
    for line in f:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/codecs.py", line 322, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x92 in position 359: invalid start byte
```

Any Help appreciated.  If in missed any required details just ask.  Thank you!

Comment: The error says that data2.txt is either not ut-8 encoded or has been corrupted. You could open it and read/print it character by character to see if it looks right. You could open binary "rb" and look at data near 359. You could `print(sys.getdefaultencoding())` on `repl.it` to see how it decodes the file. Check if the files on the two systems are identical. Generally you want to include encoding when opening a file shared among systems instead of taking the local system default.

Comment: Wow, sorry for asking such a lame question.  The file in question is an exact copy of file working on Repl.it, uploaded via FTP.  However something apparently happened during that upload to corrupt it.  Created new file in vim and issue resolved.  Is there a way to mark this solved and +rep you or anything?

Comment: Interesting. Ideally an uploader protects against corruption by writing to a temporary file and only renaming on success. If this upload is unreliable, you could also send a hash of the file and verify. `md5sum data2.txt > data2.txt.md5`, upload them both then, `md5sum --check data2.txt.md5`.